# в любом случае отвечает да. Минимальный элемент находит, а вот повторяющиеся почему-то не видит

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n, s=0;
    float min,a[10];
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf ("Введите размерность массива n \n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    printf ("Введите массив \n");

    for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%f", &a[i]);
        min=a[1];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        if(min>a[i])
        min=a[i];
    }
printf ("Минимальный элемент: %.f  ", min);


    for (i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        if(min=a[i])
        s++;
    }
        if(s==1)
        printf ("НЕТ\n");   
        else
        printf ("\nДА\n");

}
```

Comment: = и == это разные операторы

Comment: Я понимаю, если ставить просто =, то он в любом случае начинает ставить НЕТ

Comment: Медитировать сюда if(min=a[i])

Comment: Понял, благодарю

Comment: Странно, не могу закрыть вопрос